# shortest script for multiple document.getElementsByTagName('thetag') selections?

Tags: javascript

Can I select multiple items with one `document.getElementsByTagName('thetag'`)?

Like:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('thetag')[1-3]
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('thetag')[1]
document.getElementsByTagName('thetag')[2]
document.getElementsByTagName('thetag')[3]
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('thetag')` gives you all occurances of the tag `thetag` . What is the confusion ?

Comment: The problem is that I want to select three items in one sentence and javascript does not allow things like '[1-3]'

Answer (score 3):

Save the result of the `getElementsByTagName` call to a variable:

```
var theTags = document.getElementsByTagName("thetag");
theTags[1]
theTags[2]
theTags[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the OP is attempting something along the lines of what jQuery offers, in the fact that you can select multiple elements and then apply changes to that selection. The only way to achieve this is to code your own handler for this, or use a library like jQuery.

The following is an example structure, it obviously could be improved and extended in many ways, but at least shows the basics of how to achieve such a system.

```
<script>
  var selection = (function(){
    var list = [], constructor = function(){
      if ( !(this instanceof constructor) ){return new constructor;};
    };
    constructor.prototype.each = function(method){
      for(var i=0,l=list.length;i<l;i++){method.call(list[i], i, list[i]);}
      return this;
    };
    constructor.prototype.byTagName = function(tagName){
      var i, items = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName), l = items.length;
      list.length = 0; for(i=0;i<l;i++){list[i] = items[i];};
      return this;
    };
    constructor.prototype.html = function(html){
      this.each(function(){this.innerHTML = html;});
      return this;
    };
    constructor.prototype.range = function(offset, length){
      list = list.slice(offset, offset + length);
      return this;
    };
    return constructor;
  })();

  window.onload = function(){
    selection().byTagName('a').range(0,2).html('example');
  }
</script>
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">b</a>
<a href="#">c</a>
```

Getting the above working with jQuery however is rather simple, with a lot more power and flexibility:

```
jQuery('a').slice(0,2).html('example');
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer to the question. The OP isn't clear what he wants to _do_ with the selected tag; the assumption that he wants something similar to jQuery is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tags = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("thetag"),1, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.slice` returns part of an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fslice), and can also be used to [convert host objects like `NodeList` to arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fslice#Array-like). The shortest way to call it would be `[].slice.call(arrayLikeObject, begin, end)`. Both `begin` and `end` are zero-based indexes, and the element at `end` is not included.

Thus, to get everything from the second element to the fourth element, you would call:

```js
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('tag'), 1, 4)
```

If you're going to do this a lot, you could write it as a function:

```js
document.getElementsByTagNameSlice = function(tag, begin, end) {
    return [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag), begin, end);
}

// Call: document.getElementsByTagNameSlice('p', 1, 4);
```

([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/CqLL5/).)

---

**Note:** this approach won't work in IE 8 and below (nor older BlackBerry browsers) because they won't allow you to call `Array.prototype.slice` on a `NodeList`. If you need to support those browsers, your best hope is a try-catch approach inspired by jQuery's `toArray` implementation. A first attempt:

```js
try {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.documentElement.childNodes, 0)[0].nodeType;
} catch(e) {
    document.getElementsByTagNameSlice = function(tag, begin, end) {
        var tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tag),
            arr = [];

        for (var i = 0; tags[i]; i++) {
            arr[i] = tags[i];
        }

        arr.slice(begin, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should note that this will fail in IE8 and lower.

Comment: Yeah, I should. Normally I'd have done so, don't know why I forgot this time around!

Answer (score 0):

This function builds an array of the subset of nodes you want.

```
function getNodeListSubset(nodelist, start, end){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < nodelist.length && i <= end; i++){
        if (i >= start){
            arr.push(nodelist[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var subset = getNodeListSubset(document.getElementsByTagName('thetag'), 1, 3);
```